# How secure is django's cleaned_data (XSS, CSRF, SQL Injections, HTML/JS Injections, etc)?

Tags: django

Are all these risk handled by django's cleaned_data fields or do I need to implement additional security measures like strip tags?

Comment: I believe the best place for you to find out is in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/security/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling or preventing these kinds of issues is not the job of form validation.

Form validation only ensures that input data is validated and normalized to the appropriate Python data type, e.g. it ensures that a string entered in a date input is actually a valid date format and converts it to a `datetime` object.

Form validation does not prevent a user from entering SQL or HTML and it does not  do any escaping (unless you write a custom `clean()` method, or course).

The protection against the kind of attacks you describe happens in other places:

- The template library protects against XSS by treating any template variable as unsafe and escaping it for use in HTML.
- The ORM protects against SQL injection by using query parametrization.
- The `CsrfViewMiddleware` protects you against CSRF by requiring a CSRF token for POST request. It is enabled in the default settings file generated by `django-admin startproject`

For a more detailed description, check out the documentation on [Security in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/security/).